Perfboard short circuit debugging
I've got a perfboard circuit I put together that's drawing 1.7A when just the 5V and GND pins are connected. As you might have guessed, this is not ideal given the existing components.
The A4988 motor drivers got searing hot within ~12 seconds, and when I had connected it the first time to the Jetson Orin NX the Jetson shut down (I presume due to overheating of the GPIO). As a side note, I used the Jetson GPIO map to wire everything instead of the labelled one on the Pi header extension.
After disconnecting my perfboard from the Jetson I hooked it up to a power supply with just 5V and GND plugged in. This is when I noticed the 1.7A draw. Commence regret for trying to cram everything onto one perfboard (especially because pins are 1 away from each other).
What's a systematic way to look for shorts on the board? Also, what's a good way to differentiate a good vs. bad connection with the multimeter? <-My first guess there is to look at the motor driver wiring diagrams.
I've attached pictures below (witness my lovely disaster in all its glory):


Fritzing breadboard layout added 7/12. I know it's not a schematic but this is all I have at the moment. I did not add the limit switches or resistors yet. When tested on a breadboard everything worked just fine.

Step 1: Post schematic. We need to check whether the basis circuit is sound. Step 2: 5V 1.7A is a lot of power. You should be able to feel it radiate from the hot part. Best solution is to use a thermal camera and see the hotspot visually, alternatively a non contact thermometer and scan for hotspots - worst case you can spray on something that evaporates without residue - it will evaporate the quickest at the hottest area. Isopropyl alcohol, cooling spray, etc.

Look for physical shorts. Inspect with magnification. Focus on areas with many solder points - I would start looking around where the blue green and yellow wires are soldered. That looks rather messy, I would not be surprised if there was a small solder bridge there

I can't find a single acceptable solder joint on that board. Shorts is probably the least of your concerns. Solder is not hot glue, the whole point of soldering is to create a joint which has both good electrical as well as mechanical characteristics. Apart from that, wires should never be up in the air for any reason; we don't want 10+ antennas with sloppy mechanics that may cause EMC problems and/or break at any moment.

Also for currents that big, you need to present your thoughts and calculations behind the choice of wire AWG and voltage drops. If it is not supposed to draw that much current, then wth are you even doing supplying it from a voltage source without current limits? Use your bench supply.

"what's a good way to differentiate a good vs. bad connection with the multimeter?" You can't do that with solder joints because cold joints, which take up the majority of this board, may or may not conduct at any given time, especially after some time has passed and oxidation sets in. Joints need to be optically inspected, in this case the naked eye will work just fine.

@Lundin, I definitely agree with you as far as the solder joints go. I'm not happy with them either. Could you point me to some articles on troubleshooting solder problems? There are 3 issues I'm having in that regard: movement of wires while I'm soldering, improper conduction of energy in the soldering tip, and introduced impurities.
The soldering tip has black residue that builds up from something, and about 10 seconds after fresh solder is applied an oxide layer forms preventing me from easily melting solder already on the board.

@Lundin as far as wires in the air, that's the only way I could think of to connect the motor driver pins with the GPIO header extension given the close proximity of everything. Should I take everything off and switch to multiple boards so that the wiring is nicer looking and easier to diagnose?

@MrGerber I added a breadboard diagram in an edit to my original post. I do not have the right color jumper wires in the correct length to match the breadboard layout.

@Flubberknuckle There's plenty of soldering tutorials on youtube. To briefly reply: wires do absolute need to be fixed during soldering. If you can't manage to pin them down steadily with pliers or tweezers you could use tape. With some practice you can also hold the tool with index finger + thumb and the solder with index finger and middle finger. Many people like to use small jigs with crocodile clips on to fix the board. Etc.

@Flubberknuckle For conduction of energy, first check temperature. The beginner setting is around 250°C and then the joint wets slowly, but you won't have to worry as much about frying stuff. If you feel it wets too slowly crank the iron up to between 300-350°C. Or for really annoying stuff like RF connectors, ground planes etc even beyond that. Also make sure you use the right tip. Round tips are quite hard to use actually. A small flat chisel tip is what I would recommend for this job. Also for hobby stuff you can use leaded solder which is much easier to work with than RoHS solder.

@Flubberknuckle A tip for perfboards in particular would be to move the tip in to heat the board plating first, for a second or so, then move it in to the component leg and solder. One you have a proper joint there, let it cool and then you can reheat it again later to attach a wire to the leg. To fix old messy joints, use external flux like a flux pen, then reheat the joint.

@Flubberknuckle As for residue on the tip, that's flux residue and oxidation, not a problem, just clean the tip every time before use. I prefer a wet sponge, some like brass sponges, kind of depends on tip size as well. Also when done soldering for now, there's a trick to cover the tip in generous amounts of solder then turn the iron off, which will prevent oxidation on the tip when not used. If the tip is really a mess, you could buy something called a "tip cleaner" or "tip activator", which you dip the tip in briefly to clean it up (Weller is a good brand for those).

@Flubberknuckle Regarding board planning and space, it's better to use large boards when you are new to soldering. Ideally every single wire follows the board tightly and no two wires cross. That might be impossible to achieve with a small board. If you have a through-plated perf board which seems to be the case, you can also have wires on the solder side if there's no room elsewhere. Noting that currently all your wires is on the solder side :) Strictly one should try to keep them on the component side if possible, but for hobby boards it doesn't matter.

Next time make your motor driver boards pluggable. Then you can check all voltages before you insert the driver boards and potentially toast them.

@Lundin last couple questions. When I place a jumper wire on the non-solder side so that only the non-insulated portion is on the solder side, its leg will be adjacent to the GPIO or driver pin I want to connect it to. Do I wrap the jumper's leg around the pin I want to connect to, or make a solder bridge between the two through-holes? Second, is there a subreddit or something I can post pictures to get additional feedback, rather than making another post here? Best regards.

@Flubberknuckle The most correct way would be to solder the wire to the perf board then bridge using a naked wire or cut-off component leg. But I think soldering directly to the pin is ok as well. Avoid "solder bridging", there is really no such thing when soldering properly. With correctly wetted joints all solder is drawn to the metal surfaces they are supposed to join but the distance between holes on a perf board is too wide for that. So you the only way to bridge with solder alone is to make bad, cold joint.

@Flubberknuckle There is a chat on this site which is more suitable for long discussions like this. Feel free to poke me in there or start a private chat :) And then I'll reply when I have the time.

There's too much solder used and not enough flux in the right place. If you try to solder from half way up the wire, the flux in the solder will have been used up before it gets to the pad. Flux is essential to chemically clean the surfaces before the solder will combine with them.
You can search for "properly wetted solder joint" to see how they should look, there are some example photos and explanations at Adafruit: Common Soldering Problems.
If possible, please start with a new board and call the one in the question a first attempt. That way, you have some pads to have a bit of a practice on, which is always a good thing to do - you can get the feel of how much heat is needed, and how much is too much and makes the pads start to peel off (a bad thing).
I suggest that you clean the circuit board with isopropanol before starting assembly and minimise touching the bare copper with fingers (as in, don't touch it).
Touch the soldering iron to the wire and the pad at the same time for a second before feeding in the solder.
Trim soldered legs, such as on resistors, as you go along to make access to the next parts to be soldered easier.
Rotate the board to make access for soldering easier.
For soldering the wires, if you tin them first and make each end into a u-shape hook when you're going to attach them to a leg, it should be a bit easier to solder them. Don't strip back more insulation than necessary - it only means there's more of an opportunity for a short circuit.

From your comment "The soldering tip has black residue that builds up from something, and about 10 seconds after fresh solder is applied an oxide layer forms preventing me from easily melting solder already on the board.": that means the soldering iron tip is too hot. You really do need a temperature-controlled soldering iron. It doesn't need to be expensive, it just needs to have a temperature setting that works.

Would you recommend using two boards so that a) pins aren't as close together, and b) jumper wires can be run on top rather than the bottom? This would lead to me placing a jumper wire in the hole next to the pin I want it connected to, then making a solder bridge between the jumper wire and the motor driver or gpio header pin.
Also, when wires get longer should I try 'tethering' them to a pad halfway to their destination, that way they don't budge as much?

@Flubberknuckle I think you'll be fine using just the one board if you take a bit more care with soldering. I added a bit more to my answer, too.
